# oracle index for string column - does format of data affects quality of index?

Tags: performance, oracle, oracle10g

We have following type of "Unique ID" column for many tables in the database (Oracle). It is a string with following format

```
<randomnumber>-<ascendingnumber>-<machinename>
```

So we have some thing like this

```
U1234-12345-NBBJD
U1234-12346-NBBJD
U1234-12347-NBBJD
U1234-12348-NBBJD
U1234-12349-NBBJD
```

The UID value is unique, we have unique index on them.   Does the following format is more efficient than above for index scans?

```
NBBJD-U1234-12345
NBBJD-U1234-12346
NBBJD-U1234-12347
NBBJD-U1234-12348
NBBJD-U1234-12349
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a good answer for this, as it depends upon how you *query* the data. If you are typically trying to look up specific records by `UNIQUE_ID` then it doesn't matter. However, if you are looking up records by `machinename` then you would probably want that at the front of your column.

Better yet, make each of these values a separate column, and have a truly synthetic primary key based off of a sequence or GUID. That way the ordering of the data isn't an issue at all. You'll thank yourself later on.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to break these components out into separate columns (potentially with a view that generates the composite value and a function-based index to allow users to search on the composite value efficiently)